# Validate a checkboxList in yii2 always callback integer must be an integer

Tags: php, yii

In yii :

**Model**

```
class LinkReqTipe extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'link_req_tipe';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['tipe_id'], 'integer'],
        [['tipe_id'], 'required'],
        [['request_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Request::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['request_id' => 'id']],
        [['tipe_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => TipeRequest::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['tipe_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

**_form.php**

```
echo $form->field($modelLinkReqTipe, 'tipe_id')->checkBoxList(
     ArrayHelper::map(TipeRequest::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama_tipe'));
```

It generate the html (firebug see)

```
<div class="form-group field-linkreqtipe-tipe_id required">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3">Tipe ID</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input name="LinkReqTipe[tipe_id]" value="" type="hidden">
    <div id="linkreqtipe-tipe_id">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input name="LinkReqTipe[tipe_id][]" value="1"  type="checkbox"> Perbaikan
          </label>
        </div>

         <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input name="LinkReqTipe[tipe_id][]" value="2" type="checkbox"> Permintaan
          </label>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block help-block-error "></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is,
Why after submit, I still got validation that checkbox must be integer, even I have cheked at least one chekbox or more.

**controller**

```
if ($modelLinkReqTipe->load($request->post())) {
  ## validate
  $valid = $modelLinkReqTipe->validate(['tipe_id']);

  ....some code
 }
```

Debug it (one checked checkbox) :

```
modelLinkReqTipe    Object { tipe_id=[1]}
tipe_id             ["1"]
0                   "1"
```

Debug it (two checked checkbox) :

```
modelLinkReqTipe    Object { tipe_id=[2]}
tipe_id             ["2"]
0                   "1"
1                   "2"
```

Please advise.

Comment: might be because it is an array, try to use `[['tipe_id'], 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],`

Comment: tipe_id is invalid

Comment: btw just noticed, you are using `name="LinkReqTipe[tipe_id]"` and then as array `name="LinkReqTipe[tipe_id][]"`  use either as value or array, not both ...

Comment: So, what I should change ?